# Stuck on the problem, converting string to Int

Tags: python

I'm stuck on the last part of my assignment.
I'm trying to calculate the average height based on the data I scraped.
I think I have a problem with conversion feet/inches.
My idea is to split inches and feet and then use feet*12+ inches/len(total_inches) formula to calculate my result.
However I'm stuck on converting inches to numeric format.
Please help!

Here's my code:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://athletics.baruch.cuny.edu/sports/mens-swimming-and-diving/roster"
page = requests.get(url)

page.content  ##content of classes, for the problem we need "sidearm-roster-player-height" class
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
height_swimmers = soup.findAll('span', class_ = 'sidearm-roster-player-height')
print(height_swimmers)

#Extract data and place it in the list 
height_list = []

for text in height_swimmers:
    height = text.get_text()
    print(height)
    height_list.append(height)

print(height_list)

#split feet and inches
feet = [i.split("'", 1)[0] for i in height_list]
inches = [i.split("'", 1)[1] for i in height_list]
print(feet)
print(inches)

#convert string to int for feet
for i in range(0, len(feet)): 
    feet[i] = int(feet[i])
print(feet)

#convert string to int for inches
```

Comment: Hi @Daria, welcome to stackoverflow.  For these questions to have the most benefit to future readers, it is best if we can reduce a question to a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  So, you could remove most of you code, and just show us the feet to inches issue that you are facing.

Comment: @RazzleShazl While he could hardcode a list of fetched feet/inches, the code is fairly self contained and does the job fine.

Comment: @Reti43 The reason we ask for a [mcve] is so the question is more useful to other askers, and because it makes it easier for people answering to figure out what the asker actually wants an answer to, and it means the asker has to put in the effort to narrow down their problem which makes them more likely to find a solution for themselves before asking. In this case the example code also depends on a web request, which is unrelated to the actual problem, and means the code will cease to be reproducible if the website it makes a request to ever changes or disappears for some reason.

Comment: In this case if the asker had narrowed this down to a minimal reproducible example, it would be as short as `inches = int('9"')`, and probably would have meant the asker could solve it for themselves or at least know exactly what they needed to do to solve it (remove the double quote from the string).

Comment: Yes, of course it is a good thing, and it is a benefit of getting askers to reduce their problem to a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right approach, but you're creating unnecessary lists. The height (feet-inches) can be converted to inches the moment you fetch the text.

```
for text in height_swimmers:
    feet, inches = text.get_text()[:-1].split("'")
    height_list.append(int(feet) * 12 + int(inches))

mean_height = # your_code here
```

And if you want to display that back to feet and inches:

```
feet, inches = divmod(mean_height, 12)
print(f'{int(feet)}\'{round(inches)}"')
```

Comment: Hey Reti, yeah your code looks much leaner, I'm very new to python, thanks for a new approach!

Answer (score 0):

Cast your string to an int with the [int()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) function.